# Nuxt generate command create an empty html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

My application works with "npm run dev" command, but when i try to build for production with "npm run generate" in .nuxt/dist folder i have index.html with this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

i miss some configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build result of nuxt generate is in the **/dist** folder, not in the **.nuxt/dist** folder.